# Map twice the PySpark RDD to group by different keys

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I have the following `RDD`:

```
timeRange = (access_logs
              .map(lambda log: (log.date_time, 1))
              .reduceByKey(lambda a, b : a + b)
              .map(lambda s: s)
              .take(2000))

print("IpAddresses by time range: {}".format(timeRange))
```

and my schema looks like:

```
def parse_apache_log_line(logline):
    match = re.search(APACHE_ACCESS_LOG_PATTERN, logline)
    if match is None:
        raise Exception("Invalid logline: %s" % logline)
    return Row(
        ip_address    = match.group(1),
        client_identd = match.group(2),
        user_id       = match.group(3),
        date_time     = match.group(4),
        method        = match.group(5),
        endpoint      = match.group(6),
        protocol      = match.group(7),
        response_code = int(match.group(8)),
        content_size  = int(match.group(9))
    )
```

a sample log file:

```
129.192.176.24 - - [25/May/2015:23:11:16 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 200 3557 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; snprtz|S26320700000083|2600#Service Pack 1#2#5#154321|isdn)"
```

I want to group and display by timestamp, then by the IP address and its count, within the timestamp.
Right now I'm able to map over the IP address and get something like `('25/May/2015:23:11:15 +0000', 1995)`, but I was looking for something like:
`('25/May/2015:23:11:15 +0000', ('1.2.3.4', 20))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply reduce by the key `(date_time, ip_address)` in the first step then group by `date_time`.

Try this:

```
timeRange = (access_logs
             .map(lambda log: ((log.date_time, log.ip_address), 1))
             .reduceByKey(lambda a, b: a + b)
             .map(lambda x: (x[0][0], (x[0][1], x[1]))) # <=> (date_time, (ip_address, count))
             .groupByKey()
             .map(lambda x: (x[0], list(x[1]))) # this final step to get list as groupBy gives ResultIterable object
            )
```